# Linking to youtube muted - is there something like "&volume=0"?

Tags: url, youtube, href, volume, mute

I would like to include an easter egg link to youtube, that would **start the video with no sound**, is it possible?

Something like

href= http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxxxxxxxxxxx&volume=0

to prevent sound for people who would click accidentaly

EDIT: workaround, quite to my liking - linking to:

http://www.youtube.com/video_is_aloud/watch?v=Pk-bwlLbCUU

i.e. the viewer is expected to correct the address (start playing) himself

Comment: 2022 update: the *video_is_aloud* option doesn't seem to work anymore

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You don't have that option available as parameter on YouTube. Take a look at the available parameters here :

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#Parameters

Answer (score 12):

As Hugo said already you cant find an option to mute in the known parameters website, but if you will use the mute parameter it will still work.

muted:

https://www.youtube.com/embed/xY2W1As-Plo?mute=1;autoplay=1

unmuted:

https://www.youtube.com/embed/xY2W1As-Plo?mute=0;autoplay=1

Comment: 2022 update: this works, but only in browser. if you click the link on an android phone, it will open in the youtube app and override the mute setting